# Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, error404

¡Hola! Soy nuevo en la comunidad y en el mundo de la programación.
Tengo apenas un mes que estoy aprendiendo a programar y bueno, han surgido algunas dudas.

Estoy tratando de hacer un programa con **Python** y **Tkinter** en el cual al ir presionando una serie de botones arroje un resultado final.

Les muestro un poco de código:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
frame1= tk.Frame(root)

class CalcularValor():
   codigoUno= False
   codigoDos= False
   codigoTres= False
   
   def Uno(self):
       self.codigoUno= True
   def Dos(self):
       self.codigoDos= True
   def Tres(self):
       self.codigoTres= True

 botonUno= tk.Button(frame1, text= "Uno", command= 
 CalcularValor.Uno).pack()
 botonDos= tk.Button(frame1, text= "Dos", command= 
 CalcularValor.Dos).pack()
 botonTres= tk.Button(frame1, text= "Tres", command= 
 CalcularValor.Tres).pack()

 tk.mainloop()
```

Y arroja el siguiente error:

> ```
> Exception in Tkinter callback
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1885, in __call__
>     return self.func(*args)
> TypeError: Uno() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
> ```

No se si el problema esta en como estoy llamando a la clase o al método. O si es necesario crear un objeto para poder llamarlo o que onda. No tengo idea de nada (jeje).
Intente llamar a la clase y al método antes de los botones pero me arrojaba el mismo error e intente pasarle el parámetro *self* dentro del *command* pero tampoco funciono.

Se que mi error esta ahí pero no se como solucionarlo, si me pudieran echar una mano.

Por favor y gracias.

P.D. Estoy usando la versión de **Python 3.9.0 y Tkinter 8.6.** Tengo una Windows 10 y no se que mas información pueda ser de utilidad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
frame1= tk.Frame(root)

class CalcularValor():
   def __init__(self):
       self.codigoUno= False
       self.codigoDos= False
       self.codigoTres= False
   
   def Uno(self):
       self.codigoUno= True
   def Dos(self):
       self.codigoDos= True
   def Tres(self):
       self.codigoTres= True

calcular = CalcularValor()
botonUno= tk.Button(frame1, text= "Uno", command= 
calcular.Uno).pack()
botonDos= tk.Button(frame1, text= "Dos", command= 
calcular.Dos).pack()
botonTres= tk.Button(frame1, text= "Tres", command= 
calcular.Tres).pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: ¡Muchisimas gracias! Ha funcionado de maravilla.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia esto:

```
codigoUno = False
codigoDos = False
codigoTres = False
```

Por esto:

```
self.codigoUno = False
self.codigoDos = False
self.codigoTres = False
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por responder! Me temo que al adaptar la corrección no funciono, continuo arrojando el mismo error. El comentario de arriba me fue de gran ayuda pero comoquiera gracias:)

Answer (score 0):

Vale, intenta esto. En lugar de poner:

```
command=calcular.Uno
command=calcular.Dos
command=calcular.Tres
```

pon:

```
command=calcular.Uno()
command=calcular.Dos()
command=calcular.Tres()
```

El error hace referencia a self así que van por ahí los tiros. XDD

Comment: Editar tu primero respuesta no agregues una segunda y si no puede  realizar comentarios , debes esperar hasta que tengas la reputación suficiente, elimina esta respuesta y edita la primera que diste con una descripción para que sirve cada cosa que hace el código que agregaste, o te pueden dar votos negativos.